# Translation from data in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, translation

I implemented a logs system in my Django app, this system, for every action of any user will save informations in the database. Here is the model:

```py
class Log(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    log = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(to=Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

My point is on the translation of the log field. For exemple my language is english, it will save in the database "did create a new customer", But if I change the language in french I will obviously get this in english again.
Same if a french create a log I will have some logs in french others in english.
My problem is there is hundreds of different possibilities for this log field.

Is it a way with Django to translate data coming from the database in the templates like with a {% translate %} tag?

I was thinking something like having these hundreds possibilities in the translation files and Django translate it directly in the templates?

I do have the same problem with the permissions name. Users can give permissions to other users but these permission names are in english.

Thanks for your help

Comment: use google translate api

Comment: 1. Do you want that information which you save in a log field translate automatically?
2. is that string which you want to save is written by user or it is some prepared string which your system has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Django has an inbuilt method for this `.gettext()` as described in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/

This will translate the string into the end user's language. You can use it within templates or within your models.

To use it within your template:

```
<!-- load i18n -->
{% load i18n %} 

<!-- translate text -->
<title>{% translate "This is the title." %}</title>

<!-- translate string variable passed from context -->
<title>{% translate myvar %}</title>
```

In templates, `translate` calls `.gettext()` on the string under the hood.

Hope this helps ;)

Extra info:

Django's `LocaleMiddleware` will attempt to detect which language it is translating to (via a variety of techniques which you can read on the doc link).

However, if the middleware cannot detect which language the end user wants, it will use the language specified in the `LANGUAGE_CODE` variable in `settings.py`. This is the **default** language that Django will translate to.

Comment: Can you explain how can I choose the destination language with this particular example?

Comment: It is translated to the same language as specified in the user's browser.
Alternatively, go into `settings.py` and set your language code in the variable `LANGUAGE_CODE` (`LANGUAGE_CODE="de"`) to see the translation in action

Comment: My question was about how can I ***"force"*** the output to a certain language ***irrespective of my bowser/my location or any locale*** ?

Comment: Remove the `LocaleMiddleware` (the middleware which detects your locale for translation) (`'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'`) and then set the default language to translate to in the `LANGUAGE_CODE` variable. That should do the trick.

Comment: just forget about the browser thing. how can use Django's translate feature within a standalone function?

Comment: use the `.gettext()` inbuilt function.

Comment: @Nicky thanks for the answer. So if I understand it well if it's in a block translate in my template, even if it's in a var coming in the context, if the string is present in my translation file it will be translated. Am I right?
And if I am, right, how does my strings comming from the database are going in my translation file?

Comment: @Tartempion34 Yes - so when you use the `{% translate <string> %}` block in your code, it will translate the text automatically to the end user's language (Django's `LocaleMiddleware` will detect the browser's language among other factors - read above comments).

Simply pass anything you want to translate (from the database) to the template via context and wrap it in translate tags.

If this answers the question, please mark my reply as the answer.

Comment: @Nicky I still don't understand how these strings arrive in my .po file. Do II have to add them manualy?

Comment: Django will automatically import the strings into the `.po` file so you can provide translations. To do this, read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/

`python3 manage.py makemessages`
If you mark your strings with `{% translate %}` the makemessages command will import those strings into your `.po` file.